# What is virtualbox.service and is it safe to disable it?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, systemd

I am trying to speed up boot of my computer by disabling unnecessary services.
Here's the output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
      12.745s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      8.032s dev-sda2.device
      4.828s accounts-daemon.service
      4.528s NetworkManager.service
      3.802s grub-common.service
      2.926s virtualbox.service
      2.821s preload.service
      2.769s networking.service
      2.726s virtualbox-guest-utils.service
      2.537s ondemand.service
      2.476s speech-dispatcher.service
      2.419s systemd-logind.service
      2.411s thermald.service
      2.407s loadcpufreq.service
      2.049s lm-sensors.service
      2.042s alsa-restore.service
      2.041s gpu-manager.service
      2.001s lvm2-monitor.service
      1.945s systemd-udevd.service
      1.740s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.706s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.683s hddtemp.service
      1.206s setvtrgb.service
      1.082s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.021s keyboard-setup.service
      --More--
```

I wonder what virtualbox.service is and if it is safe to disable it.
I don't use any VMs though have Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager installed.

Comment: Or just uninstall it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use VirtualBox than you can disable it.  Also if your not using VirtualBox then you could just uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm also interested in what the service does, why VirtualBox needs the service.